# Launch another intent from AndEngine activity

Tags: android, andengine

I have two activities, MainMenuActivity and GameActivity, that each inherit from AndEngine's BaseGameActivity. I'm trying to launch the game from the main menu:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), GameActivity.class));
finish();
```

This is being called from within onSceneTouchEvent. This causes the application to crash in PoolUpdateHandler::onUpdate, on the line that says "synchronized (scheduledPoolItems)".

I feel like this should be simple. Any clues?

Comment: also you can substitute `getApplication()` with `this`

Answer (score 0):

Try the suggestion with swapping out `getAppliction()` with `this`. You want to pass in a reference to the current activity's context rather than passing in your application reference.

Answer (score 0):

This works for my game:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));
finish();
```

In which "this" is the andengine gameActivity.